# Hibernate schema parameter doesn't work in @SequenceGenerator annotation

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, schema, sequence, jpa-2.0

I have the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table", schema = "my_schema")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_table_id_seq", sequenceName = "my_table_id_seq", 
                   schema = "my_schema")
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "my_table_id_seq", 
                    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

}
```

Database: Postgresql 8.4, Hibernate annotations 3.5.0-Final.

When saving the object of MyClass it generates the following SQL query:

```
select nextval('my_table_id_seq')
```

So there is no schema prefix and therefore the sequence cannot be found. When I write the sequenceName like

```
sequenceName = "my_schema.my_table_id_seq"
```

everything works.

Do I have misunderstandings for meaning of schema parameter or is it a bug? Any ideas how to make schema parameter working?

Comment: I had the same problem here and put the schema on the sequence name, like you did. My @SequenceGenerator doesn't have a schema property.

Answer (score 8):

My workaround looks like this (JPA 2.1, Hibernate 4.3.8.Final, PostgreSQL 9.4):

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_name", sequenceName = "my_schema.seq_name", schema = "my_schema", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Same problem here, looks like a bug to me. I´m using hibernate 3.6.7
Looking at the source code i see a method `org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverridenAnnotationReader#buildSequenceGeneratorAnnotation(Element element)` that seems to copy the values of `name`, `sequence-name`, `initial-value` and `allocation-size`attributes, but I see no reference to `catalog`or `schema`

i expected to see something analogous to method `getTable(Element tree, XMLContext.Default defaults)` (of the same class) which has

```
annotation.setValue("schema", table.schema());
annotation.setValue("catalog", table.catalog());`
```

or `buildTableGeneratorAnnotation` which has

```
copyStringAttribute(ad, element, "catalog", false);
copyStringAttribute(ad, element, "schema", false);
```

So, even if a little hackish, the way around -for this version at least- seems to be prefixing the `sequenceName` as you say.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem in postgresql 9.6 by only adding my schema before the sequence name, like this:

```
(before) sequence name: seq_area_tematica
(after) sequence name: sisbp.seq_area_tematica
```

And its works. See the code:

```
@Id
@Column(name="seq_area_tematica")
@GeneratedValue(generator="sequence",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) 
@SequenceGenerator(name="sequence",sequenceName="sisbp.seq_area_tematica")
private Long id;
```

See the "sisbp" before the sequenceName. The sequenceName was "seq_area_tematica" and now is "sisbp" (schema) + "seq_area_tematica".

Answer (score 2):

Using Hibernate `4.2.0.Final` here and have the same problem. Looks like it is a bug like answered by another users. I wanted to use a dynamic schema for sequences, depending on the schema set for the session, but for some sequences I wanted to use `public` schema. So for me I had to use the solution you proposed: put the schema name on sequence name where I want to use a specific schema:

```java
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_table_id_seq", sequenceName="my_schema.my_table_id_seq",
 schema = "my_schema")
```

For the cases where I wanted to use the schema set for the session I used the `sequenceName` without the schema prepended.

**For those that want the same schema for all sequences** you can use  `hibernate.default_schema` property. With that you don't need to change your `@SequenceGenerator` properties:

```xml
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">my_schema_name</prop>
```

I am using PostgreSQL DBMS. If you want to change dynamically the name of the sequence when Hibernate calls `nextval('my_sequence')` you can extend your database dialect class and configure Hibernate to use. You need just to override `getSequenceNextValString()` method. The only information provided to the method is the `sequenceName` property defined on `@SequenceGenerator`:

```java
public class SchemaPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL82Dialect {
    @Override
    public String getSequenceNextValString(String sequenceName) {
        String seqFinalName = mySequenceNameModifierMethod(sequenceName);       
        return "select nextval('" + seqFinalName + "')";
    }

    private String mySequenceNameModifierMethod(String originalSequenceName) {
        // magic modification here
        return modifiedSequenceName;
    }
}
```

I didn't use this last way to change the name of the sequences because it seems less appropriated to my case.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug: the JPA provider should honor the "new" (since Java Persistence 2.0) [`schema`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#schema()) and [`catalog`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#catalog()) attributes of the [`@SequenceGenerator`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) annotation. I suggest to raise [a Jira issue](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH) (the annotations and entity manager projects are now under core), couldn't find any existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, using Hibernate 4.3.6.Final, with Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE, on Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0.

Looks like this is a bug => https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7232

We got around the issue by creating a synonym in schema A pointing to the sequence in schema B. This synonym was what we used in the schema attribute of @SequenceGenerator annotation

Comment: allegedly fixed in version 5.x: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7232?focusedCommentId=74395&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-74395

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I don't work with the internals of hibernate much but there is some info here:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2406761

You can also set the default schema for a user connecting to PostgreSQL via ALTER USER ... SET SEARCH_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the SequenceGenerator annotation from the POJO's class declaration to *id* field declaration.  With Hibernate 3.6.4 this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table", schema = "my_schema")
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "my_table_id_seq", 
                strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_table_id_seq", sequenceName = "my_table_id_seq", schema = "my_schema")
    private int id;

}
```

produces this for MySQL

```
create table my_schema.my_table_id_seq (
     next_val bigint 
);

insert into my_schema.my_table_id_seq values ( 1 );
```

and this for PostgreSQL

```
create sequence my_schema.my_table_id_seq start 1 increment 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the execution does not go through the location indicated by @jambriz.

Version: Hibernate 3.6.10.Final

The problem occurs when `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false` in `persistence.xml`. When set to `true` or simply remove, the sequence scheme is used by Hibernate to build SQL. **Solution:**

```xml
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
<!-- Or remove this property -->
```

Where's the problem in the code?

In the [AnnotationBinder.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.6.10.Final/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationBinder.java#L445-L480) class between lines 445 and 480. In the `if` block, line 455, you can see the scheme being set. In the else the scheme is not set.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

when using hibernate with spring
please set

```
<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my app which is using Hibernate 5.2.7, with Spring 4.3.6, on Oracle Database 19c. Changing sequenceName = "MY_SEQUENCE" to sequenceName = "MY_SCHEMA.MY_SEQUENCE" worked perfectly.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@SequenceGenerator(schema = "MY_SCHEMA", name = "MY_SEQ_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "MY_SCHEMA.MY_SEQUENCE")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_SEQ_GENERATOR")
private Long id;
```

Answer (score -5):

Hello i was having same problem

but set your hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to update and run.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: I know it's way after the fact, but this answer is incorrect because it would just create the generator in the default schema, which might not be where you want it.